# Nested forms error "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been stuck on this for days and tried all the solutions I could find online but no luck.

I have a Student linked to many Transfers. Each transfer is linked to a Classe.

To make the form I use the following classes : StudentType, TransferType.

The StudentType form classe had a field of type TransferType. Codes below.

StudentType.php

```
<?php
// src/PS/PSchoolBundle/Form/StudentType.php

namespace PS\PSchoolBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use PS\PSchoolBundle\Entity\Responsible;
use PS\PSchoolBundle\Entity\AuthorizedPerson;
use PS\PSchoolBundle\Entity\Transfer;

class StudentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('subNumber', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('subDate', 'date', array(
                        'required'  => false,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')
                    ))
            ->add('lastName', 'text')
            ->add('firstName', 'text')
            ->add('lastNameSecondLanguage', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('firstNameSecondLanguage', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('birthDate', 'date', array('required'  => false,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')
                    ))
            ->add('birthPlace', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('birthPlaceSecondLanguage', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('gender', 'choice', array('choices' => array('' => 'Veuillez choisir', 'm' => 'Garçon', 'f' => 'Fille')))
            ->add('nationality', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('homeLanguage', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('bloodType', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('familySituation', 'choice', array('required'  => false,
                                                            'choices' => array(
                                                            '' => 'Veuillez choisir',
                                                            'm' => 'Mariés',
                                                            'd' => 'Divorcés',
                                                            'w' => 'Veuve',
                                                            'a' => 'Autre')))
            ->add('schoolStatusBefore', 'choice', array('required'  => false, 'choices' => array('' => 'Veuillez choisir', 's' => 'Scolarisé', 'ns' => 'Non scolarisé')))
            ->add('remark', 'textarea', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('responsibles', 'collection', array('type' => new ResponsibleType,
                                                      'prototype' => true,
                                                      'allow_add' => true,
                                                      'allow_delete' => true))
            ->add('authorizedPersons', 'collection', array('type' => new AuthorizedPersonType,
                                                      'prototype' => true,
                                                      'allow_add' => true,
                                                      'allow_delete' => true))

            ->add('transfers', 'collection', array('type' => new TransferType,
                                                      'prototype' => true,
                                                      'allow_add' => true,
                                                      'allow_delete' => true));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'student';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'PS\PSchoolBundle\Entity\Student'
        );
    }
}
```

TransferType.php

```
<?php
// src/PS/PSchoolBundle/Form/TransferType.php

namespace PS\PSchoolBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use PS\PSchoolBundle\Entity\Transfer;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class TransferType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('reason', 'choice', array(
                        'choices' => array('success' => 'Réussite', 'failure' => 'Échec'),
                        'required'  => false
                        ))
            ->add('date', 'date', array(
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')
                    ))
            ->add('school', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('classe', 'entity', array('class' => 'PSPSchoolBundle:Classe', 'property' => 'name'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'transfer';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'PS\PSchoolBundle\Entity\Transfer'
        );
    }
}
```

When I added the "classe" field to the TransferType, instead of showing the form, I get this error thrown :

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed 500 Internal
>   Server Error - FormException

Please note that I have tried TransferType and the form shows correctly with classe choice field populated. This problem only arises when I use the TransferType and the StudentType together.

Thanks

Edit - Below is the action of the controller that generates the form:

```
public function byIdEditAction($id)
{
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        if(!$student = $em->getRepository('PSPSchoolBundle:Student')->find($id))
        {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Student[id='.$id.'] does not exist.');
        }

        $form        = $this->createForm(new StudentType(), $student);
        $formHandler = new StudentHandler($form, $this->get('request'), $em);

        if($formHandler->process())
        {
            $this->get('session')->setFlash('wehappy', "L'élève a été mis à jour.");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_studentsbyidshow', array('id' => $student->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('PSPSchoolBundle:Student:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'student' =>  $student
    ));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller which generates the form?

Comment: Just added the action that generates the form. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I looked at your code and everything seems fine. The error seems to suggest that the Classe object is not managed by the entity manager. I suppose that this class is managed by Doctrine. Is it? Not really sure what else could be wrong

Comment: Yes it is a Doctrine entity. This problem was occuring when trying to edit a Student that had at least one Tansfer. I deleted a Transfer and checked again and found that the problem didn't occur, then strangely, I put the Transfer back and everything now works fine.
Very weird...
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually linked to the fact that I'm using a StudentType that has an entity field (Transfer) which itself has an entity field (Classe).
The transfer object that was linked to the Student object did not have a Classe linked to it and thus I had that exception thrown complaining about the fact that the Classe object, that needs to be added to the Classes choice field was not managed. That means that it has to be managed by the entity manager. In other words, it had to be coming from the database.

There are two ways to fix this problem :
The obvious one was to fix the link that was missing on the database as that relation is set to not nullable on Doctrine.
The second way was to create a default Classe object and pull it from the data base, then assign it to the transfer like so :

```
if(!$classe = $em->getRepository('PSPSchoolBundle:Classe')->find(-2))
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Classe[id='.$id.'] does not exist.');
    }

    $transfer->setClasse($classe);
```

before actually creating the form using the StudentType...

Hope this helps somebody.